# TestFlight current build has expired

Tags: ios, testflight

Now I have uploaded new Build (incremented Build Number) with same Version Number, it's not available for Testing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to upload a new version. Once a build is expired, version expired too.